# MongoDB. Вычисления в аггрегациях

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate, агрегация

Имеется следующая коллекция (привожу описание `Mongoose`-схемы):

```
{
    student: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true }, 
    exercise: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
    task: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
    startTime: { type: Date, required: true },
    endTime: { type: Date, required: true },
}
```

Смысл коллекции в том, чтобы трекать количество времени, затраченного студентом при решении одного задания. Если студент дважды отвечал на задание, то будет добавлено два объекта с одинаковыми идентификаторами, но разными `startTime` и `endTime`. 
Задача такова, что требуется достать получить из базы данных массив объектов следующего вида:

```
{
   _id : UniqueId,
   student : ObjectId;
   task : ObjectId;
   timeSpent : number;
   median : number;
}
```

Объект будет характеризовать, какое количество времени (в секундах) студент потратил на решение задания - поле `timeSpent` и какое количество времени в секундах в среднем тратят все ученики на решение данного задания - поле `median`.

Требуется написать агрегацию, которая бы высчитывала `timeSpent` и `median`. По дополнительному условию требуется использовать только последние данные, т.е. если студент отвечал 4 раза на одно задание, то требуется в финальный результат предоставлять только 4-ый объект.

Расчёт поля `timeSpent` не занял особого труда. Ниже приведу пример агрегации:

```
const sessions = await Session.aggregate([
        { $match: { exercise: toObjectId(exerciseId) } },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: {
              studentId: '$student',
              taskId: '$task',
            },
            task: { $last: '$task' },
            exercise: { $last: '$exercise' },
            student: { $last: '$student' },
            startTime: { $last: '$startTime' },
            endTime: { $last: '$endTime' },
          },
        },
        {
          $addFields: {
            timeSpent: {
              $divide: [{ $subtract: ['$endTime', '$startTime'] }, 1000],
            },
          },
        },
    ]);
```

Сложности возникают при расчёте `median`. `median` должен высчитываться, как среднее арифметическое всех `timeSpent` студентов по одному заданию (`task`) и вписываться в каждый объект рядом с полем `timeSpent`. Каким образом, можно рассчитать median в одной агрегации с расчётом `timeSpent`?

Answer (score 0):

После долгих раздумий нашёл решение данной проблемы:

```
const sessions = await ProblemSession.aggregate([
        { $match: { exercise: toObjectId(exerciseId) } },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: {
              studentId: '$student',
              taskId: '$task',
            },
            task: { $last: '$task' },
            exercise: { $last: '$exercise' },
            student: { $last: '$student' },
            startTime: { $last: '$startTime' },
            endTime: { $last: '$endTime' },
          },
        },
        {
          $addFields: {
            timeSpent: {
              $divide: [{ $subtract: ['$endTime', '$startTime'] }, 1000],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: '$task',
            task: { $last: '$task' },
            studentStats: {
              $push: {
                student: '$student',
                timeSpent: '$timeSpent',
              },
            },
          },
        },
        {
          $addFields: {
            median: { $avg: '$studentStats.timeSpent' },
          },
        },
        {
          $unwind: '$studentStats',
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            task : 1,
            median: 1,
            student: '$studentStats.student',
            timeSpent: '$studentStats.timeSpent',
          },
        },
      ]);
```